# confused over proper way to use json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to jquery and just started reading up on json early last night.  **I have a working ajax call that passes simple data to a php script, works on the data and returns a single value.** Works great.

**I want to add the passing of arrays and non array data back and forth** and after reading piles of articles saying json IS the way to go!!!!  BUT... also that json isn't secure, ... put braces, dont put braces - use json decode, dont use it, make sure the top item is an object, some say put a "d" at the top, some use serialization, some don't use it.  Do I have to put the curley braces around the data?  Or does Jquery.  Some people have said to also add a header that specifies application/json or some other header... and others have said it breaks IE7...  some have said to add ...

`"dataType" : json`

in the ajax call.  Do you see why I am confused now?

... and ... In the PHP do I have to also use rawurldecode? before json decode since my ajax urlencodes the data ...  it's sooo confusing...

I don't want this to be a bigger security hole than it already is... I would like to do it PROPERLY and to SPEC. if there is a spec.

Most people thankfully say... it's about HOW you use it (jquery, JSON) etc and THAT makes it "secure".  And by secure... I mean, used properly.  Nothing on the client side is EVER secure.

What I'm stuck on is simple I'm sure but after reading for over 9+ hours I can't find a definitive answer.  Why can't the people who make the languages (Jquery) write an example that says... here's the PROPER way to do it now that we have included json support!?!

And yes, I'm being a tad wordy in this top portion because I've asked short questions before and been downvoted and criticized and accused of not researching things or not "looking into it enough" when I NEVER ask a question here without at least 5+ hours of intense reading, scanning websites, etc.. and usually I only come here after way over 9+ hours ...

...but the information I have found is broken, old, and in too many pieces and I want to do it PERFECTLY!!! :)  The best website I found so far was for pulling in flicker pictures but it didn't show how to send properly so I left there happy to find the article... but didn't know how to apply it to MY situation...

*Please see the comments in my code for the tips I need please or even better - fix up my code so I can send those 2 datas back and forth and in each language can you assign a value to a tmp variable so I can SEE how you extract the information from the passed data?  Thanks...*

JQUERY/JS (my old code) (code snippits)

```
    //Here's some sample data... - HOW DO I SEND THIS AS JSON (please) back and forth?
    var myarray = new Array();
    myarray.push("One");
    myarray.push("Two");
    myarray.push("Three");
    var someOtherData = "helpmeplease";

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../ajax/ajax.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({
            "testarray" : myarray,
            "somemoredata" : someOtherData
        }),
        success: function(results) {
            // what do I do with results?  please alert the 2 passed variables back from php
            // for example alert("Test:" . results[0] . results.someOtherData) or however you
            // access the returned values...
```

PHP RECEIVE FROM AJAX (my old test code)

```
     $test1 = rawurldecode($_POST["somemoredata"]);
     $test2 = rawurldecode($_POST["testarray"]);
     $test3 = testarray[0]; // should be One
```

PHP RETURN

```
     // please send any data back to the Ajax call 1 array, 1 normal data please and alert
     // the data please so I can see how it's pulled back out...
     return $data; // 1 array, 1 normal variable please
```

More info on my stuff...

- my website is UTF-8 encoded
- My data set will be under 4 megs.  Most likely under 200k.
- No cross domain stuff taking place
- I have a nonce, per page token authentication system that works great
- what can go in the data?  ANYTHING?  Any symbols, or stuff that should NOT be included that would break the JSON code or the passing of data back and forth?
- any other tips, suggestions, warnings?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Off-topic. but to get to the answer sooner, Make your question brief.. no one wants to read 100 lines.. :)

Comment: I made my last question very short and was downvoted and criticized for not researching it so I deleted it.

Comment: Screw that. It's a good question; I'd like to learn more about this too. +1.

Comment: This is anything but a good question. Asker apparently needs tutoring, not a "definitive answer". Most jQuery methods have very clear, very _definitive_ examples in the documentation.

Comment: You cannot make an informed choice between conflicting advices, because you haven't made the effort to _understand_ them and are trying to just use them as-is.

Comment: Every single person who asks a question on here needs some sort of tutoring... or they wouldn't be here.  While the jQuery docs show me jQuery examples of code on the client side... they don't show how the code appears in "other languages".  Wheres the PHP example to show a brief server side example?  As a beginner to json and web programming in general... I find it hard to sort through the volumes of information and mis-information and poorly programmed examples littered throughout the internet.  I came here to hopefully ask a professional for their help and opinions.

Comment: I did that so I didn't have to find out later that.. gee... I had an incomplete knowledge of the subject matter.  When someone says... "you should go in this direction" and "try this" I pool it with my other knowledge.. some of the blanks get filled in.. and my understanding grows. It does take a certain level of experience to be able to even read and understand some of the docs in PHP and other languages.  Around Christmas of this year I hit that level with PHP... I had enough "background" to read the docs and figure it out for myself.  Prior to this "enough background" I struggled to

Comment: read anything but the simplest docs, functions, and structure of the language.  I came here asking for an answer so I could OBSERVER how it's properly done.  I spent many hours over 2 days reading and reading.  I had all these pieces and I was hoping someone here would say... "do it this way because..." and the final pieces fall together.

It appears I didn't need to use JSON anyways from the nice example below.  It appears I was VERY close to an answer anyways.  I was just unsure.

And I am wordy because if I hadnt of specified enough details then it ends up goes back and forth and people

Comment: pur forth useless examples because they were guessing on what I was trying to do which is understandable because they have no background of my knowledge, what Im trying to do, etc.

I made the effort.  I needed clarification.  I don't want a crappy swiss cheese security breachable website.  

I want to do it right.  And many people here have gobs more experience than I have.

Why not ask someone instead of guessing only to find out later on when it's live that I missed something and my website is hacked.

Comment: Also...  regarding lengthy explanations...   What takes less time?  A DETAILED explanation of something that entails my knowledge, what I really want done, and how an answer would actually help me OR a brief short note on what I want.  

Then everyones misconceptions as to what THEY think I was trying to say come into play.

I would say... a little extra reading up front to lay the foundation so I can get surgical answers instead of blobs of uselessness that have nothing to do with what I wanted to accomplish.

Well, thats all I have to say. Well, I have lots more.. but. :)
Have a nice day!

Comment: Hope you find my answer helpful.  Getting data in and out of JSON format is a breeze.  Manipulating it is as easy as manipulating arrays and objects in JS or any other language with native JSON support. If you have further questions about how to structure JSON, or why, after seeing my answer, feel free to ask, and I'll try to answer -- but also, it might help at that point to become more fluent in JavaScript objects and arrays - especially nesting objects and arrays in other objects/arrays, and how to rationalize it, reason about it, and write functions to match your goals and structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to send data as JSON, it would mean to include other libraries for nothing. You can use jQuery to send data as array, and read it as array in your PHP script.

Eg:

1. Returning a single var from PHP:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function(){
       var myarray = new Array();
       myarray.push("One");
       myarray.push("Two");
       myarray.push("Three");
       var someOtherData = "helpmeplease";

       $.ajax({
           url: "../../ajax/ajax.php",
           type: 'POST',
           data: ({
               "testarray" : myarray,
               "somemoredata" : someOtherData
           }),
           success: function(results) {
               alert(results);
           }
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

   and your script:

   ```
   <?php
       $testarray = $_POST['testarray'];
       echo $testarray[0]; // prints One
       $someOtherData = $_POST['someOtherData']; // prints helpmeplease
   ?>
   ```
2. Returning the data to jQuery as array and other single variables.

   You add `dataType: "json"` and return data as JSON:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function(){
       var myarray = new Array();
       myarray.push("One");
       myarray.push("Two");
       myarray.push("Three");
       var someOtherData = "helpmeplease";

       $.ajax({
           url: "../../ajax/ajax.php",
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: ({
               "testarray" : myarray,
               "somemoredata" : someOtherData
           }),
           success: function(results) {
               alert(results.somemoredata); // will alert 'helpmeplease'
               alert(results.testarray[1]); // will alert 'Two'
           }
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

   and script:

   ```
   <?php
       // I used the same POST fields, but it can be any other data
       $array = array();
       $array = $_POST['somemoredata'];
       $array = $_POST['testarray'];
       echo json_encode($array); 
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help in answering my question.  I understand more now.  At the time of posting this I wasn't sure what json actually was and how to use it.  It seems I was close to a solution but you helped put the final pieces together for me.  Much appreciated!!!

I have been sending and receiving various types of data back and forth since yesterday.  Works great!

Comment: JSON requires libraries? When? Both JS and PHP have built in functions for JSON.

Comment: (hey Doug, just saw this now years later) a lot of documents I read back then, mentioned libraries you needed, along with all sorts of quirks in using them, bad characters you couldn't use... that's what I mean when I said... outdated, bad information out there...  hard to understand how to do something correctly when so many people have tutorials that are outdated, or poorly put together...

Now, JSON is super easy.  :)  Looking back at my old questions.. wow, I barely knew anything.  lol.

Answer (score 2):

Okay.  First, the easiest way to think of JSON is a serialized representation of a JavaScript Object (or an n-dimensional, associative/non-associative set of arrays, if you think more easily in PHP).

As an example in PHP, you might do something like:

```
$albums = array( array( "title" => "Dark Side of the Moon",
                        "artist" => "Pink Floyd",
                        "tracklist" => array( "Speak to Me", "Breathe", "..." ) ),

                 array( "title" => "Ten",
                        "artist" => "Pearl Jam",
                        "tracklist" => array( "Once", "Even Flow", "..." ) )
);
```

You can do the same thing in JavaScript in a more-compact fashion, like:

```
var albums = [
    {
      title : "Dark Side of the Moon",
      artist : "Pink Floyd",
      tracklist : [ "Speak to Me", "Breathe", "..." ]
    }, {
      title : "Ten",
      artist : "Pearl Jam",
      tracklist : [ "Once", "Even Flow", "..." ]
    }
];
```

The two are exactly the same thing.
JSON will serialize that collection of arrays and objects, to look almost exactly like the JavaScript implementation.

**NOTE 1:** *each of the double-quotes below should be escaped, but I really won't do that by hand*
**NOTE 2:** *the whole thing will likely be a 1-line double-quoted string, as per standard, but doing that here breaks syntax-highlighting, which I think you'll get more out of*

```
[{"title":"Dark Side of the Moon","artist":"Pink Floyd","tracklist":["Speak to Me","Breathe","..."]},
{"title":"Ten","artist":"Pearl Jam","tracklist":["Once","Even Flow","..."]}]
```

As you can see, JSON doesn't really require any schema except one that you create, yourself, to fill your particular need.
Here, I've got an array of albums.  Each album has a `title` an `artist` and a `tracklist`, which is an array of song-titles.
If your application warranted, you could turn `tracklist` into an array of `track` objects, each with its own song-title and duration and link to lyrics or the .mp3 or whatever you want it to do.

Because I'm using an indexed-array of objects (I don't need to give each album an associative name in my albums collection - an indexed array can hold them), the JSON string is wrapped in square brackets, the same way a JS array is (JS arrays are ***index-only***).

It's REALLY lightweight, compared to XML.

If all you're doing is sending a few keys and values back and forth, then some simple query parameters on top of a RESTful API is more than enough.

If you are sending something that's more an "associative array" (an object in JS), then equally-valid would be JSON which looks like:

```
{"title":"For the Record","artist":"Nerds with Guitars","tracklist":["Sympathy for the Daleks","Hero","Stereotypical"]}
```

You've only sent one object, because you only had one object to send.
Objects are denoted with braces in JS, so in JSON, if you've got one single object with named-properties, it's going to be wrapped in braces.

**NOTE 3:** *if you use a library like jQuery, or grab JSON from an API like Twitter Search, even if you only get one object back, it's likely that it will come back to your JS program as a single object, inside of an array, so reading the last example might have to be done like:

```
var dataArr = JSON.parse(response),
    dataObj = dataArr[0]; //only object in array

displayTracklist(dataObj);
```

If you're doing all of this yourself in vanilla JS, you can choose whether the response comes back as an object, with named properties, or as an array of whatever you'd like (usually an array of objects).
You might have both kinds in an app, if you know that one call (like sending login POST data) will ALWAYS return a single object with named properties, and other calls will return lists of objects (like getting comments for a blog post, or getting blog posts for a blog-roll, or getting data from the server for each player in a multiplayer game).
Whether you want to treat the two cases differently is 100% up to you.

On the PHP side of things, you will use `json_decode` to turn these into associative arrays.
Be sure to read the documentation on `json_decode`...  ...it defaults to 1-dimensional arrays, which is really dumb, and an easy thing to forget.
Use `json_encode` to turn your arrays (indexed or associative, or n-dimensional combinations of the two) into JSON strings.

So to operate on the data, all you need to do is write some functions which are going to traverse your own structure of arrays/objects, to do what you want them to do, rather than worrying about ugly DOM-based node-traversal, XML-style.

On the JavaScript side of things, you're going to use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to do your decoding and encoding.

When you send these over the wire, my suggestion is to use simple "text" headers.
If you send them with a MIME type of `application/json`, you won't need to do any of the decoding, in any language.
***HOWEVER***, IE6 and IE7 have absolutely ***NO*** native support for JSON.
As such, if you send that MIME type, they're going to have a fit, because they'll need special treatment in your app, where you'll have to decode, but only in those browsers, et cetera...

Moral of the story: `text/plain` and `var dataObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);`

For IE6 and IE7, use Douglas Crockford's `json2.js`.
Either put the download of the file inside of a conditional-comment for `IE lte 7`, or include it for everybody -- it's tiny, and if you have a JSON-enabled browser, it won't do anything at all.
The native implementations of JSON are built on json2.js, so as far as you need to be concerned, IE6 and IE7 will then have the same JSON-abilities as Chrome21 and IE10.

Most JS libraries also have their own built-in JSON serializer/deserializer, based around the json2 spec.

Speaking of specs...
...what can and can't you put in JSON?

Well, basically, you can serialize anything that's a native JS object, which is data-based.

So functions, RegEx, DOM-elements, HTML5 APIs, other crazy ideas you might have are out...
but strings, numbers (all JS numbers are floats, so JSON has no number types), booleans, arrays and objects are all in, with one exception:
You can't have any circular references in your structure.

var myObj = { child : { parent : myObj } };

Totally valid JavaScript.
JSON will refuse to encode it.

So yeah, JSON is as safe as you want to make it.
It doesn't allow functions, so there's no harm in accessing something and having it blow up in your face, as long as you ***NEVER EVER `eval` WHAT YOU RECEIVE*** and instead serialize and deserialize in controlled ways...

...and of course, sanitize your inputs and outputs, as always, and it'll be as safe a data-transfer mechanism as anything else.

**Addendum:** don't bother building JSON strings by hand, like some people suggest...
...that's fugly, error-prone, and just not worth the effort, when you can make arrays/objects in less time, and traverse them, extend them, whatever, and then let JSON recurse through your structure and serialize as it goes.

Comment: Hey there, thank you also for your very detailed answer.  Some of it I didn't fully understand but the thing I liked is... you filled in some other blanks and questions I had.  Wish I could give 2 answers but I ended up using the other guys answer before you posted.  However... your post helped me fill in some blanks especially regarding the IE6 and IE7, the app type and how it works, and where to use the alternate libraries if needed.  I have read so much bad about eval also.. I'll never use it.  I'm used to 6502 assembly language on the Commodore 64!!!  LOL.  Trying to wrap my head

Comment: around all this OOP, and plus, I havnt programmed for 17 years (as of last year) - I've been studying my butt off and sometimes I'm sick of having to look up yet something else before I write another statement.  It's very frustrating especially considering I could made games in ASM!  LOL.  Thank you for your time and effort.  It's much appreciated... my old brain isn't as sharp as it used to be back in the early 80's.  But... I'll code till I die now. :)  Should never have stopped.  My favorite thing in the whole world!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague.  In general, your question communicates one thing clearly:  you don't know what JSON is or how to use it.  Therefore, the answer is, "STUDY."

A general answer:  JSON is for *data exchange*.  How you use it will depend entirely on what you are trying to accomplish in any particular situation.  for example:

**encoding a javascript object as a JSON string:**

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.aString = 'a string of characters';
myObj.aList = ['a','b','c'];
var myJSON = JSON.stringify( myObj );
console.log( myJSON ); 
// {"aString":"a string of characters","aList":["a","b","c"]}
/*    
note - the function you use varies by browser/javascript engine.
libraries (jQuery, for example) have methods that can simplify this.
*/
```

**decoding a JSON string into a PHP array**

```
$myJSON = '{"aString":"a string of characters","aList":["a","b","c"]}';
$myArray = json_decode( $myJSON,true );
print_r( $myArray );
/*
Array
    (
    [aString] => a string of characters
    [aList] => Array
        (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
        )
    )
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't read the entire post since is very very long  but you should take a look at this functions. make sure you pass and get the variable in the same format (array or json or etc).

```
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
```